# Wafv2 with terraform. how to do I exclude rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, web-application-firewall

I created a WAFV2 as a modules and this is part of my code

```
  name        = var.name
  description = "WAFv2 ACL for ${var.name}"

  scope = var.scope

  default_action {
    allow {}
  }

  visibility_config {
    cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
    sampled_requests_enabled   = true
    metric_name                = var.name
  }

  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = var.managed_rules
    content {
      name     = rule.value.name
      priority = rule.value.priority

      override_action {
        dynamic "none" {
          for_each = rule.value.override_action == "none" ? [1] : []
          content {}
        }

        dynamic "count" {
          for_each = rule.value.override_action == "count" ? [1] : []
          content {}
        }
      }
```

But after setting up kinesis firehouse I noticed some requests are been blocked by WAFV2, can anyone help me to figure out how to exclude some of the AwsManagdRules been blocked? here are some examples of them.
**"CrossSiteScripting_BODY", "GenericLFI_BODY"**

but I tried something like this one below in the tableau server using the waf is this correct?

````
      name            = aws_wafv2_rule_group.aws-wafv2-tableau.name
      arn             = aws_wafv2_rule_group.aws-wafv2-tableau.arn
      priority        = 0
      override_action = "allow"
      excluded_rules  = ["CrossSiteScripting_BODY","GenericLFI_BODY"]
  }]```
````